# Delete all records 3 number above of my table id with this name and mac

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete all records in my table 3 id's above of some table id with particular stop_name and mac.

For example if the table id is 13 I want to delete all records 3 id's above of my position also from table id 10 with the stop_name `alex ally` and mac `F6:k9:g4:9M:6G:b8`.

For more comprehensibility:
What I am trying to achieve before inserting the new `stop_name` kohlmarkt if it is difference from the previous one I want to pick the records with the min distance, min speed and max speed and inserting them to my table after that I want to delete all these record with the `LindenAcadren` nam and the mac `10:A5:D0:06:C6::E9` above my 3 new inserted records. The name and mac might be anyone.

[image]

How can I query it?

I appreciate any help.

**behaviour table:**

```
                   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS behaviour(
                            behaviour_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                            stop_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                            stop_distance INT(11) NOT NULL, 
                            speed INT(11) NOT NULL,
                            created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you please provide some sample data and the expected output of the query? Also, what have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: @PrerakSola: I have updated my question. Please would you take a look at it?

Comment: No pics please. Just proper DDLs and a desired result.

Comment: @Strawberry: I am using phpmyadmin can I create DDLs with it?

Comment: Of course. It's just need the CREATE statements (which you've done) and enough INSERTs to be properly representative of the problem.

Comment: I just to delete all records with some stop_name and mac 3 id's of the last record id.

Comment: What do you mean to say be `3 id's of the last record` ? If the above are your rows in your tables, which are the rows that you want to delete?